# Is querying a particular folder faster?

Tags: caml

I have a folder in document library.

If I get the folder from folder collection of the document library and only query the items inside that folder will it work faster then querying a whole library using the recursive attribute? Just to be clear I only need the items that reside inside that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely it will be faster, as less items will be retrieved and stored in memory.

Here's sample code,

```
public void SaveFolderFiles(string fileName, string libraryName, ClientOM.ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        ClientOM.List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        ClientOM.CamlQuery camlQuery = new ClientOM.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Site/Folder/Folder2010/";
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View>
            <Query>
              <Where>
                <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>
                  <Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + @"</Value>
                </Eq>
              </Where>
              <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
            </Query>
          </View>";
        ClientOM.ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        if (listItems.Count == 1)
        {
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024524/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-with-camlquery-file-download-but-no-conten)

[CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property is the key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx)

Comment: thanks mate , by the way can you post here an example of caml where items from only a particular folder in the doc library are accessed

Comment: Check updated answer.