# How to get SPListItemCollection from a SPFolder?

Tags: web-part, folder, splistitemcollection

I am making a SharePoint 2010 visual web part, and I want to recursively iterate through all files in a document library which has nested folders. I can get a SPListItemCollection  for all items and folders in the top level. As I iterate through the files, I can check if the current file is a item or folder. If its a folder, how can I get a SPListItemCollection  object for everything in that folder? When I check the API, the closest method returns a SPFileCollection...

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67272/is-querying-a-perticular-folder-faster/67274#67274

Comment: I fail to see that as a dupe. The linked question is different, even if the answer happens to contain some code that could fit this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get items collection very simply. Try this code:

```
public static SPListItemCollection GetItemsRecursive(SPFolder folder)
{
    SPList list = folder.ParentWeb.Lists[folder.ParentListId];
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Folder = folder;                        //set folder for seaching;
    query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""; //set recursive mode for items seaching;
    return list.GetItems(query);
}
```

This code return only file items, folder items will missing. If you need get file items and folder items, set view attribute "Scope" to "RecursiveAll".

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";
```

Comment: Can this code be changed to make it work for client object model? Because my Folder object does not have `ParentWeb` or `ParentListId` properties.

Comment: So, you may get it values as method params. And what client object model you mean? (C#.NET / JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

From the SPList, grab the RootFolder property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder.aspx).

In the RootFolder (an SPFolder) use Files property to get the SPFileCollection in the folder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.files.aspx).

Then on the RootFolder (and each subsequent subfolder), use the SubFolders property to iterate through each subfolder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.subfolders.aspx).

Something like:

```
var rootFolder = list.RootFolder;
foreach (SPFile file in rootFolder.Files)
{
// do something
}

foreach (SPFolder folder in rootFolder.SubFolders)
{
foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
{
// do something
}
}
```